# AngularJS - Creating a floating scroll down/back to top button

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm running into an issue and I see no way out.

I have one page app and I'm currently using angular-scroll for navigation. Now, what I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

I have two "img" buttons one is ScrollDown and another is ScrollUp. Is there any way to create a directive as part of angular-scroll and/or AngularJS? when a user clicks on a ScrollDown button,It will scroll to the next div id (maybe place ids in some kind of array where the current location will be saved, therefore the click to trigger scroll to next array value in line) and when a user scrolls to the bottom, the button should change to ScrollUp and a click should return the user to the top of the page.

I hope I have explained this well, any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. just a note, the app is pure AngularJS, so there should be no jQuery dependency.

EDIT

I should also point out that I'm just learning Angular right now, so any help would be really appreciated.

This is what I'm currently using for navbar nav:

```
var ScrollApp = angular.module('myApp.ScrollApp', ['duScroll', 'ngAnimate']).value('duScrollOffset', 60);

ScrollApp.controller('ScrollCtrl', function($scope){
        var container = angular.element(document.getElementById('container'));
        var sectionhome = angular.element(document.getElementById('Home'));
        $scope.toTheTop = function() {
            container.scrollTop(60, 5000);
        };
        $scope.toHome = function() {
            container.scrollTo(sectionhome, 60, 1000);
        };
        $scope.scrollVariable = false;
    }
);
```

Is there a way to append a directive to a controller below, that will contain an array of section anchors, add a location watch so when user clicks on the button, it takes him to a next div id in line and when he reaches the bottom, the button image to change and take user back to top.

I hope that the question is properly formulated now.

Comment: use *$location.hash(div#id)* to locate the anchor tags; and then call *$anchorScroll()* to move the scroll to either upwards or downwards based on selected div#id.

Comment: Is it too much to ask for you to show me how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('scrollCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.ids = ['id1','id2','id3','id4','id5'];
}]);

app.directive('myScroll', [ function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div id="template" style="position:fixed; top: 2px;left: 35px;"><input type="button" value="up"  ng-click="up()"><input type="button" value="down" ng-click="down()"></div>',
    scope: {
      ids: '='
    },
    controller: ['$scope','$location','$anchorScroll', function ($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
      
      var current = 0;
      
      var scrollTo = function (id) {
        $location.hash($scope.ids[id]);
        $anchorScroll();
      };
      
      $scope.down = function () {
        if ($scope.ids.length - 1 > current)
        {
          current++;
          scrollTo(current);
         
        } else {
          current = 0;
          scrollTo(current);
        }
      };
      
      $scope.up = function () {
        if (current > 0)
        {
          current--;
          scrollTo(current);
        } else {
           current = $scope.ids.length -1;
           scrollTo(current);
        }
       
      }
    }]
  };
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="scrollCtrl">
    <my-scroll ids="ids"></my-scroll>
    <div ng-repeat="id in ids" style="height:500px; background-color:yellow;">
      <div id="{{id}}">
        <h3>{{id}}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

--SJ

Comment: Awesome, I get it now and I was able to implement the same logic on angular-scroll, so I could get the smooth scrolling. Now, my question is, is there a way to implement this on a single button instead of two buttons? And when the user reaches bottom, for button to change from down to up? I'm maybe being a pain in the a. but I really need this.

Comment: It's very simple logic. i guess, you can do it by yourself. :)

Comment: Ok, I do appreciate all your help, I will surely try to figure out something.